# How to get the ID from a Google+ vanity URL

Tags: google-plus

How to get the ID from a vanity URL, e. g.?

https://plus.google.com/u/0/s/tesla%20roadster

There are many posts about how to get the vanity URL but not the opposite.

Answer (score 8):

The URl you posted is actually a search not a vanity URL. A vanity url looks like this https://plus.google.com/+TeslaMotors.

But to get the ID from a vanity URL, you can make a request to [people.get](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people/get) API method with the +Name as the userId. [Here is an example request](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/plus/v1/plus.people.get?userId=%252BTeslaMotors&_h=1&).

Comment: Now the reverse :) how do i get the vanity from the ID

Comment: The same people.get method using the userId and then parse the url field in the response.

Comment: Note that as of April 2019, Google+ has been shut down, so these methods do not work (and it’s quite possible that if the GAIA id wasn’t grabbed prior to the Google+ shutdown that it may be impossible now).